# Using Arzela-Ascoli to prove there's a converging sub-sequence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, arzela-ascoli

I am trying to solve the following problem in preparation for an upcoming exam in introductory topology and I'm unable to complete it entirely. My problem is with (b), but I've stated the full problem since it is likely that (a) is required for (b):

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.

a. Prove that every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

b. Let $T,S : X \rightarrow X$ be isometries.
Let $f_1 \in C(X,\mathbb{R})$. Denote $f_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\Big(f_n(T(x))+f_n(S(x))\Big) \quad\forall x\in X, n\in \mathbb{N}$ .
Prove that $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a converging subsequence using the sup norm.

So I've tried the following two approaches:

1. Use Arzela-Ascoli by first proving $F:=  \{f_n\}$ is closed, bounded and equicontinuous. It seems impossible to prove it is closed - maybe I'm missing something? (tried assuming by contradiction there is a $g$ in $cl(F)$ not in $F$ but this didn't take me too far).
2. Proving the space is complete (since $X$ is compact $C(X,\mathbb{R})= B_c(X,\mathbb{R})$ and using the fact that $X$ is a topological space and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete) and then trying to prove that $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, therefore converges, therefore has a convergent subsequence. Also got stuck in this case, although it seems more promising due to the isometries, but not sure.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you can't show $F$ is closed, it's probably not. You can apply your version of the theorem to the closed set $\overline F$. (Exercise: If $F\subset C(X)$ is equicontinuous then so is $\overline F$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How can you see so quickly that it's probably not true that it's closed? (thanks for that tip! Forgot about that option... will try to go ahead with that direction and see if it helps).